# Why does the is-operator cause unnecessary boxing?

Tags: c#, boxing

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#-constant-pattern) of constant pattern matching with the `is`-operator (`expr is constant`) states:

> The constant expression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. If `expr` and `constant` are integral types, the C# equality operator determines whether the expression returns `true` (that is, whether `expr == constant`).
> 2. Otherwise, the value of the expression is determined by a call to the static `Object.Equals(expr, constant)` method.

---

Therefore, when using this code

```
public bool IsZero(int value)
{
    return value is 0;
}
```

I expect it to use the `==` operator (case 1) and generate this code:

```
.method public hidebysig instance bool
    IsZero(
       int32 'value'
    ) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8

    ldarg.1
    ldc.i4.0
    ceq
    ret
}
```

---

However, in [reality](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQUQI4FcCGEDOAavgJL4ICwAUAN4L2VUNKIBGA9uxAmQFoCmAJ3YAKMADtgCAG54s/AJSNmNas2YwA7DLn8EYcgAYA3GoYBfauaA==), the integer parameter and the constant (literal) are boxed in order to be passed to the static `Object.Equals` method (case 2):

```
.method public hidebysig instance bool
    IsZero(
       int32 'value'
    ) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8

    ldc.i4.0
    box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
    ldarg.1
    box          [mscorlib]System.Int32
    call         bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
    ret
}
```

---

Why is that the case?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/164/c-sharp-7-micro-benchmarking-the-three-ways-to-cast-safely) helps

Comment: Are you sure you were examining correct IL code? I've tried and there was no boxing.

Comment: @SᴇM what compiler did you use? For me, both VS17 and SharpLab (see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQUQI4FcCGEDOAavgJL4ICwAUAN4L2VUNKIBGA9uxAmQFoCmAJ3YAKMADtgCAG54s/AJSNmNas2YwA7DLn8EYcgAYA3GoYBfauaA==)) produce the CIL present in the question.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I'm using VS19. Can you share the whole IL code of `IsZero` method?

Comment: @SᴇM I edited the question to include the whole method code. I removed only comments and the labels.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow What framework version do you use? I've just noticed if I change from `4.6.1` to `4` it boxes the value.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow you can use Sharplab.io to try different compilers. You are correct, older Roslyn versions do box while the *newer* that implement C# 8 features don't

Comment: @SᴇM I used `4.7.2` with VS17... and it still boxes.

Comment: Sorry, it was just the difference between VS versions (and `c#` versions too). I believe that's because of new [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#pattern-matching) feature, which apparently checking value type's type without boxing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is the same in all cases - Roslyn. Different versions produce different IL though. The C# 8 versions don't box, while older ones do.

For example, with [2.9.0](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOOBNRhARgPaMQECSAzgFoCmATowAUYAHbACANwCGEAK48AlDkrZaRAOySZ8gmA4EADAG4cAXzNA=) the IL for this snippet :

```
using System;
public class C {

    public bool IsZero(int value)
    {
        return value is 0;
    }
}
```

is

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_0007: ldarg.1
    IL_0008: box [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_000d: call bool [mscorlib]System.Object::Equals(object, object)
    IL_0012: stloc.0
    IL_0013: br.s IL_0015

    IL_0015: ldloc.0
    IL_0016: ret
```

Using any of the [C# 8 versions](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoYQ3c3ACYgA1AB8AAgCYAjAFgAUJIDMAAhlqAwmoDeSpWqMb1wDh1xqCyAFpkOACjYk1ANyi44EAJSHj+xWMgjQB2Nw8vNTZkNQAGAG4/IwBfJWSgA==) though produces this in debug mode :

```
    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0003: ceq
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    IL_0006: br.s IL_0008

    IL_0008: ldloc.0
    IL_0009: ret
```

and this in [Release](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAmARgFgAoHAZgAJ9KBhSgb1NMtequAHtONKBJKAC1EnABRoAdjEoA3CBgCucAJQs2TEmy3UA7LPlLKaKJQAMAbjWsAvqWtA=).

```
    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: ceq
    IL_0004: ret
```

That's the same as the expected code in the question

Answer (score 1):

[is operator Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#-constant-pattern) states:

> When performing pattern matching with the constant pattern, `is` tests
>   whether an expression equals a specified constant. **In `C# 6` and earlier**
>   **versions, the constant pattern is supported by the `switch` statement.**
>   Starting with `C# 7.0`, it's supported by the `is` statement as well.

By default VS2017 using older version `C#` compiler. You can enable `C# 7.0` features by installing `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) which can be used to compile the code with the latest version of the compiler.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos No that's not true, I've selected `C#` version `7.0` and it generates IL without boxing. Even though, if you change version to `6.0` it will generate compiler error: _"Feature 'pattern matching' is not available in C# 6. Please use language version 7.0 or greater."_

Comment: I checked and even when I used C# 7.3 (that's the latest selectable in my VS17 version) it still generates the boxing instructions. It might likely have something to do with VS19, I think.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Can you provide more details about how you checked that?

Comment: I went to `Project Properties > Build > Advanced > Language Version` and selected `C# 7.3`. For the record, my VS version is `15.9.12` and the compiler (I assume that is the compiler) reports as `C# tools version 2.10.0 beta2` in the `Help > About Visual Studio` window.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow I guess VS2017 by default is not using new features of the new compiler and I've noticed, that if you install `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` from `NuGet` it will use new compiler instead of the VS2017 default one. Also, check this post about [What is the Purpose of Microsoft.Net.Compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533613/what-is-the-purpose-of-microsoft-net-compilers)

Comment: Thank you. I will try the package asap. I upvoted your answer as you really tried to help me, and I appreciate that.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow you're welcome! Yeah, I was curious too.